# Why do different versions of .net (or the compiler) generate different expression trees for the same expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees, system.reflection

In one of my libraries, I have code that returns a MethodInfo from an expression:

```
public MethodInfo GetMethod(Expression expression)
{
    var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)expression;
    var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambdaExpression.Body;
    var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    var methodInfoExpression = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments.Last();
    return (MethodInfo)methodInfoExpression.Value;
}
```

I had a series of helper functions to enable calls like the following:

```
public MethodInfo Func<T, R, A1>(Expression<Func<T, Func<A1, R>>> expression)
{
    return GetMethod(expression);
}
```

This would enable the following syntax:

```
var methodInfo = Func<TestClass, bool, string>(x => x.AnInstanceMethodThatTakesAStringAndReturnsABool);
```

This worked great, until I recently upgraded the library to .Net 4.6.1 and the latest c# compiler.

In the previous version of .net, the expression would be of the form:

```
{x => Convert(CreateDelegate(System.Func`2[System.String, System.Boolean], x, Boolean AnInstanceMethodThatTakesAStringAndReturnsABool(System.String)))}
```

Hence my code would look for the methodInfoExpression as the last argument of the methodCallExpression.

Now, in .Net 4.6.1 (latest c# compiler), the compiler seems to be producing an expression of a different form:

```
{x => Convert(Boolean AnInstanceMethodThatTakesAStringAndReturnsABool(System.String).CreateDelegate(System.Func`2[System.String, System.Boolean], x))}
```

My current code breaks because the last argument is not a ConstantExpression.  Looking at it - easy fix, just change to

```
 var methodInfoExpression = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Object;
```

Obviously, the GetMethod function is pretty fragile and subject to changes to how the compiler generates expressions.  I'm curious as to the reason for the change and how I might refactor GetMethod so that it is more resilient to the expression tree generated by the compiler.

Comment: You should really post example code that compiles when providing an example.  And if you want help writing the method more effectively you should actually describe what it needs to do, rather than just showing the non-working version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm curious as to the reason for the change

As of .NET 4.5 there were two ways of making a delegate from `MethodInfo`:

1. An instance method on `MethodInfo`, and
2. `Delegate.CreateDelegate` static method

It looks like Microsoft decided to switch from using #2 to using #1, for whatever reason (it's probably more efficient).

> how I might refactor `GetMethod` so that it is more resilient to the expression tree generated by the compiler?

You could use [expression tree visitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and look for the method info that way.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks!